# Unable to read json response from requests library

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm doing a post request to a website and trying to read the response it gives me back. However, when I try to read the response it's not readable. I don't know if this matters, but I am also in a session with the website.

I have tried converting the response to ascii by using `resp.decode("utf-8")`, using `resp.json()`, and `resp.text`. None of which have worked and result in either unreadable text or an error saying it's was unable to decode it. I have made sure that I'm getting a 200 response code and that the return headers state that the `content-type` is `application/json`.

```
import requests, json

resp = sesh.post(play_url, headers=headers, json=data)

print(resp.json())
```

The error I receive occurs when I try printing `resp.json()` and the error is,

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)".
```

Sample of the website's response:

```
b'!\xfc\x08\x00 \xbe\xb8_*\xfft\x0e\xd2r\xdc\xf1\xc8m\xc2|\xc8\x11\xb5\x03\x1a\xb8)v\xc4\x02\x0b0\xe6w,{\x0f\xe4\xbc\x03\x96``\xb5\xd1\xa6szi\xa2\x87>b\xb0\x85\xee\xe4X\xfe\x17\xadV\xc8/\x92\xf9\x1f\x02\x97}\xb0\xc9\x98\xa8-\x08\x1c\xca\x10L\xdff \xb8\x90 \x15\x19U\xc2\xae<\xec6[\xe4\\x84\xf7g\x88\xf1)\x13\xea\xf6\xae\x05\xa8\x0c\xf1\x02\xf7\xa3\xdb6\xe7N\xb7C\xb86E\x19(\x08\x0fsrZ\xad\x13\x85\x07 \x18\x0f\xc7\xeb\x0e\x83\xf0\xb9;\xdb\xbc\x0c\xc2\x8f\x8bu:<\x96\xce\x977xn\x14Q\xfc$\x1f\xc6\xd1\x18\xcb\xfc\x0f:\xf9\xd4t\x87\xeb\xa5\x0eq\x7fVx\xadM}/\x10Q\xd3\x06z\x12\x05\x1a\xed \xbd\xf7\x8d\x0b1\x05o\x1b\x10b\xaaB\xc67\x7f\x9e\x9b\x93B\xf0\xa2\x1b=7\xf7o\xd0\xe3\x0b\x905C\x14\x98\x9d\xbf@\x12\x13>\xb1/\x10f?\x8cLH6\xe6\xcaX\xcb\x99\xb4\x90\x8a\x02\x10\xf6\xc1\xe3\n\xd7\xb5\x9f:#i\xf8\x8b\x96\xb2\xbb\x9cG\x1b\xd5($\xfd!>\x95\x9e\x94\xff\xff\xff\x07'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that application-type doesn't dictated the encoding type. The response headers define the encoding type via this response "accept-encoding" : "br".

To decode the response I used the following code:
brotli.decompress(resp.content)

The resp variable is the response from the website.